# I've hit the character limit for a formula and when I try shortening it, I'm unable to

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a pretty large data set I with adresses and postal codes, and I need to organize said data set by postal codes only, which resulted in a large number of variables.
The code goes like this (it continues for a long while, but in order to shorten it for easier access and reading:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NEPAL";F2));RIGHT(F2;5);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MALTA";F2));RIGHT(F2;5);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SWITZERLAND";F2));RIGHT(F2;5);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CHINA";F2));RIGHT(F2;5);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CHILE";F2));RIGHT(F2;5);"OTHER"))))))`

I had to translate the formula since I'm using EXCEL in Portuguese.

TL'DR: My formula hit the character limit (it's a lot bigger than what's above) and I still have some variables I need to add to the formula (eg.):

`IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ANGOLA";F2));RIGHT(F2;6)`

and other variables with the same functions.

If anyone could help me shorten the string, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Would it in such case not be the absolute easiest to have a lookup-table with all countries and an adjacent column with the number of characters you need from the right?

Comment: maybe you can convert it into a VBA function and do the magic there

Comment: FWIW, you can shorten any bits that return the same character length using something like: `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"NEPAL";"MALTA";"SWITZERLAND";"CHINA";"CHILE"};F2));RIGHT(F2;5);"OTHER")` but I'd agree a table is a better solution generally.

Comment: Agree with @JvdV. It looks like something a xlookup or vlookup can easily solve (procx or procv, in portuguese).

Comment: As mentioned above by @JvdV Sir, create a table of reference and use a `LOOKUP()` Function like `=RIGHT(LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(Table_Reference_Range,F2),F2:lastrow),5)`

Answer (score 0):

Used the solution sugested by @Rory and it worked perfectly for what I wanted! Thank you all!

Comment: This is not a complete answer. You could comment in the post and share your suggestions.